# How can I use ImportXML to insert the NAME OF A SITE into Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find the XML tag to use to insert the name of a website into Google Sheets.

For example, if using the URL https://www.newsweek.com/joe-biden-ireland-peace-deal-under-threat-1792858

I need one column with the title of the article, and another column with the name of the website.

I've used IMPORTXML("//title")) to insert the title of the article, "Joe Biden Heads to Ireland With Peace Deal Under Threat" into the first column

But need to figure out the XML tag to insert the title of the website, "Newsweek" into the second column.

Thanks!

I've tried IMPORTXML("//meta")) and getting "parse error"

Comment: In your question, if you want to use other URLs except for `https://www.newsweek.com/joe-biden-ireland-peace-deal-under-threat-1792858`, can I ask you about them? Becuase even when the result can be retrieved from your showing URL, when that cannot be used for other URLs, that might be an issue for your situation. I'm worried about it. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I just used that particular URL as an example. Mostly the list is about media sites, so it might be https://www.nytimes.com, it might be https://www.youtube.com, it might be https://www.cbsnews.com. It could be any number of different sites.  I just would want a column that can scrape the name of the site ("New York Times;" "YouTube;" "CBS News") just as using "title" can scrape the title of an article.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I just used that particular URL as an example. Mostly the list is about media sites, so it might be nytimes.com, it might be youtube.com, it might be cbsnews.com. It could be any number of different sites.`, when I could find a xpath for achieving your expected results from those various URLs you want to use, I would like to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Tanaike I started using =REGEXREPLACE(E7, "https://www.","") to get rid of the "https://www" part of the url, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to also get rid of ".com*" and everything after that.